# google social login not working 100% - cognito/amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I just setup amplify with google as a social login, but it doesn't appear to be working 100%. I have it setup to redirect to the homepage after logging in. When I click the google login button, it doesn't always go to the google signin page. It's inconsistent. I do have times where it does go there though. I know this sounds odd so I created a 16 second video to demonstrate it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90e_9jD8SG4

I don't understand what I am missing. Here's some screenshots of my settings in cognito user pool and  google developer console. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help!

Here's my app client page

[image]

Google developer console

[image]

User pools > identity providers > google

[image]

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
  CognitoUser,
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUserSession
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import Auth, { CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { ICredentials } from '@aws-amplify/core';
import { User } from './shared/models/user.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthData } from './auth-data.model';
import { RegisterModel } from './signup/register-model';
import { CONFIG } from '../config';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: CONFIG.UserPoolId,
    userPoolWebClientId: CONFIG.ClientId,
    mandatorySignIn: false,

    //domain name from user pools > app integration > domain name
    oauth: {
      domain: '<my-domain-name>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
    }
  }
});

const POOL_DATA = {
  UserPoolId: CONFIG.UserPoolId,
  ClientId: CONFIG.ClientId,
};

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(POOL_DATA);

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  authIsLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  authDidFail = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  authStatusChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
  public loggedIn: boolean;
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();

  private _authState: Subject<CognitoUser | any> = new Subject<CognitoUser | any>();
  authState: Observable<CognitoUser | any> = this._authState.asObservable();

  public static SIGN_IN = 'signIn';
  public static SIGN_OUT = 'signOut';
  public static GOOGLE = CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google;
  registeredUser: CognitoUser;
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  socialSignIn(provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider): Promise<ICredentials> {

    return Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider });

  }

  getAuthenticatedUser() {
    return userPool.getCurrentUser();
  }

  logout() {
    this.getAuthenticatedUser().signOut();
    this.authStatusChanged.next(false);
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    const user = this.getAuthenticatedUser();
    const obs = Observable.create((observer) => {
      if (!user) {
        observer.next(false);
      } else {
        user.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            observer.next(false);
          } else {
            if (session.isValid()) {
              observer.next(true);
            } else {
              observer.next(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    return obs;
  }

  initAuth() {
    this.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (auth) => this.authStatusChanged.next(auth)
    );
  }
  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusChanged.asObservable();
  }

  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }
}

...
```

google signin function in login.component.ts

```
  async signInWithGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    let socialResult;

    try {
      socialResult =
        await this.authService.socialSignIn(AuthService.GOOGLE);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("E", e)
    }
    console.log('google Result:', socialResult);
  }
```

Comment: Hej, did you solve the problem?

Comment: You can use the cognito hosted UI to login via google or other social providers. Much easier to use. If you go to user pool and click launch hosted UI in settings. Use that URL for logging in and then set the redirect URL back to your app.

Comment: @mch.zawalski did you find a solution ? Face same issue.

Comment: lol this was over 2 years ago. I don't recall the specifics of this issue. To debug it try and hit ctrl + z/cmd + z in address bar to see what last url was between hosted ui and your app. usually it gives a hint of an error message like invalid client or something. developer console and cognito app client page do look correct from my screenshots though.